# Force subdomain in Firefox to redirect to https of the specific subdomain

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, nginx

I have 2 servers with nginx. All is working fine for my main server, like the following scheme:

- https://MYSERVER.eu/ => https://www.MYSERVER.eu/
- https://www.MYSERVER.eu/ => https://www.MYSERVER.eu/
- www.MYSERVER.eu/ => http://www.MYSERVER.eu/
- MYSERVER.eu/ => http://www.MYSERVER.eu/

But on the second server where I use **owncloud**, it has a small misbahaviour when using the Firefox browser:

- https://oc.MYSERVER.eu/ => https://oc.MYSERVER.eu/
- oc.MYSERVER.eu/ (Chrome) => http://oc.MYSERVER.eu/
- oc.MYSERVER.eu/ (Firefox) => ***https://www.MYSERVER.eu/*** (wrong!)

I don't know why it redirects to the **www** subdomain.

The server configs are:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    root        /var/www/www;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name www.MYSERVER.eu;

    if ($host ~* 'oc\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$')  {
        set $host_without_www $1.$2;
        rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://oc.$host_without_www$1 permanent;
    } 

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/pem.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/private.key;

    location / { 
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
            rewrite ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
            rewrite ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)?(/.*\.php)$ $2 last;
            rewrite ^ /index.php last;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri/ $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /doc {
        root /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
    location /images {
        expires 168h; 
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }       

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www/www;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl    on;

    root        /var/www/owncloud;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name oc.MYSERVER.eu;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/pem.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/private.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

    index index.php;
    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /(favicon.ico|robots.txt) {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    } 

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    } 

    location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

        rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

        rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        try_files $1 = 404;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   htaccessWorking true;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $2;
        fastcgi_param   HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
        expires 30d;
        # Optional: Don't log access to assets
        access_log off;
    } 
}
```

Is this an Firefox bug or feature? I mean in Chrome this does not happen. But in Firefox he redirects to the wrong server. I have completely no idea why he do so.

Extra: I also would like to know how I'm able to do this one:

(I want to force SSL here on the oc subdomain):

- http://oc.MYSERVER.eu/ => https://oc.MYSERVER.eu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this fixed it for me. And I had to **wait one day** till the **DNS/router** got the latest information. So don't expect that changes are working instantly. Now **after a day** it works in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

So the basic idea about this aproach is **creating a subserver** that is listening on port 80. This one redirects to https when a http is requested. As I said it's really hard to test, because browser puffers the config and you always need to wait some minutes or even days to check the current state.

But finally it works. So this is what you need to edit:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name www.MYSERVER.eu;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name oc.MYSERVER.eu;
    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }   
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ssl    on;

    root        /var/www/owncloud;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name oc.MYSERVER.eu;
    ...
}
```